# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did not understand what is the reason of this bug, could anyone help me?

`IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
(at Assets/Scripts/PlayerCar.js:73)
CompareApproximately (det, 1.0F, .005f)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()`

**My code:**

```
var GearRatio : float [ ];
var CurrentGear :int= 1;
var EngineTorque:float=230.0;
var MaxEngineRPM:float=3000;
var MinEngineRPM:float=1000;
private var EngineRPM: float = 0.0;

function Start () { 
        rigidbody.centerOfMass += Vector3(0, -1f, 0.25f);
}
function Update () {
        EngineRPM =( FrontLeftWhell.rpm + FrontRightWhell.rpm)/2 * GearRatio[CurrentGear];
        ShiftGears();

        FrontLeftWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) * motorInputTouch;
        FrontRightWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) *  motorInputTouch;        
}

function ShiftGears(){

        if(EngineRPM>=MaxEngineRPM){
        var AppropriateGear: int =CurrentGear;
        for (var i=0;i<GearRatio.length;i++){
                if(FrontLeftWhell.rpm * GearRatio[i]>MaxEngineRPM){
                    AppropriateGear=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        CurrentGear=AppropriateGear;
}

if(EngineRPM <=MinEngineRPM){
    AppropriateGear=CurrentGear;
    for (var j=0;j<GearRatio.length;j++){
        if(FrontLeftWhell.rpm * GearRatio[i]>MinEngineRPM){
            AppropriateGear=j;
            break;
        }
    }
   CurrentGear=AppropriateGear;
}
```

Comment: Wait, is that unityscript?

Comment: This line `if(FrontLeftWhell.rpm * GearRatio[i]>MinEngineRPM){` near the end, shouldn't it be `[j]` instead of `[i]`?

Comment: yes,i tried many method but i could find solutions:(

Comment: Your error says that the exception is thrown at  `Assets/Scripts/PlayerCar.js` on line 73. What's on this line?

Comment: (71-)EngineRPM =( FrontLeftWhell.rpm + FrontRightWhell.rpm)/2 * GearRatio[CurrentGear];

  (72-)  FrontLeftWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) * motorInputTouch;
 (73-)   FrontRightWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) *  motorInputTouch;

Comment: You have a GearRatio array. Did you properly fill that with values in the Inspector? If not, and immediately setting the CurrentGear to 1 (the 2nd gear) you will get the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

i think , problem is just this  line

EngineRPM =( FrontLeftWhell.rpm + FrontRightWhell.rpm)/2 * GearRatio[CurrentGear];

```
    FrontLeftWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) * motorInputTouch;
    FrontRightWhell.motorTorque = (EngineTorque /GearRatio[CurrentGear]) *  motorInputTouch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your last `if` statement in the ShiftGears function:

```
if(FrontLeftWhell.rpm * GearRatio[i]>MinEngineRPM){
```

Your loop is using `j` as the current index, but you are using `i` to access the GearRatio array. Use `j` here instead.